# Server stops responding to pings and remote requests

Tags: suspend

Am running 18.04 desktop on a Lenovo m91p behind my firewall as a server for mysql, cassandra and elasticsearch. It goes unaddressed for long periods of time and I then find that it is unresponsive to requests. Sometimes pinging it will wake it up, but usually not. I have to go downstairs and push the power button to wake it.

Is this because I installed the desktop version instead of the server? I am not even sure what is going on. Is there anyway to wake it up remotely? Or keep it from going to sleep? Is installing the server version my best option?